# Проблема с Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

При попытке восстановить/обновить VS2019 возникает следующая ошибка:

```
[1f8c:0012][2019-06-14T21:54:00] Error 0x80131500: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path ''.
   в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   в Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   в Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   в Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Serialization.ModelSerializer`1.Deserialize(TextReader reader)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.DirectoryRepository.GetPackage(IPackageIdentity identity)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.GetPackage(IPackageIdentity identity)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.GetRegisteredProduct()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Repair(CancellationToken token)
```

Кто нибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поврежден диск, на котором стояла VS. Помогло только полное удаление, через установщик невозможно было совершить какое-либо действие, всегда такая ошибка, поэтому для полного удаления используйте:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe
```